# How do I say "API (application programming interface)" in Russian?

Tags: терминология, информатика, сокращения

How do I say "API (application programming interface)" in Russian? Is there maybe some acronym (aside from АПИ) that makes it easy to read in translation from English to Russian?

Comment: I always spell it as `АПИ`.

Comment: Orally you should totally use `АПИ`, not sure about writing. And note, that in Russian it will be read as a word, rather than as an acronym ([апи], not [а-пэ-и] and definitely not [эй-пи-ай] as in English)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Written out, the term is [программный интерфейс приложения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API). In colloquial speech, one could use:

- **программный интерфейс,** just a shorter form
- **интерфейс,** if it's obvious from the context that it's not *"графический интерфейс"*
- **библиотека,** as often an API is packaged into a library.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to have a term to use for some official paperwork, like legal documents or technical documents, the other answers provided might be helpful. However, in colloquial speech, nobody ever calls API anything else other then АПИ or (yeah, we like diminutives) апишечка.

So, in real life you'll hear not "Валерий, нам для этого нужен новый программный интерфейс" but rather "Валер, ну тут без того, чтобы новую апишечку запилить, не обойтись".

Comment: Agreed 100%! And for official papers it makes sense to not translate API at all, just keep it `API`.

Comment: As a programmer in Russia, I totally agree. Colloquially, we never use "программный интерфейс" and other long versions. We spell it "API" (in English letters) and say "апи". I'm not sure about the stress though. I personally prefer "ап*и*" and the diminutive "ап*и*шка", but I've heard "*а*пи" from many colleagues.

Comment: The reason for diminutive, I'm pretty sure, is so that it could be declined like a normal noun word.

Answer (score 3):

Bing translate and Google translate say:
**Интерфейс программирования приложений**
To me, this seems more correct. I also googled Russian books about programming and found out that there's no consensus on this.
For example, in

https://books.google.ru/books?id=hk8NmSqOkFsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru

**Набор базовых интерфейсов программирования приложений**

[Another book with Ы](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/28267159/)
[and without Ы](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vay1dnm9QIcC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru)

**Интерфейс[ы] прикладного программирования**

Comment: I agree, the Russian term _must_ distinguish between a _user_ (like in G**U**I, M**U**I) and a _programmer_ doing some _programming_ with its help (like in A**P**I), while a version like _программный интерфейс_ sounds absolutely the same as _интерфейс программы_ which is about _any user_.

Answer (score -1):

Call it API — everybody will understand. It's almost untranslatable. If you want to write an official document, call it программный интерфейс приложения or программный интерфейс.